# How to make SwiftData document-based app coexist with Core Data using same persistent container from the document

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, swift-data

I am working on a SwiftData document-based app. Most things were progressing pretty well until I tried to build more complicated predicates; specifically the lack of NSCompoundPredicate-like support in SwiftData. I have been trying to incorporate Core Data to coexists in my app so I can use FetchRequest when I need complicated predicates.  There isn't a lot of information available. I have looked at Apple documentations, WWDC videos, SO, HackingWithSwift, etc.

If you know how I can get a NSManagedObjectContext from the SwiftData document modelContext in my app, please advice.

My simplified App code is below:

```
    @main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(editing: .myAppDocument, migrationPlan: MyAppMigrationPlan.self) {
            MainWindowView()
        }
    }
}

extension UTType {
    static var myAppDocument: UTType {
        UTType(importedAs: "com.example.myApp")
    }
}

struct MYAppMigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [VersionedSchema.Type] = [
        MYAppVersionedSchema.self,
    ]

    static var stages: [MigrationStage] = [
        // Stages of migration between VersionedSchema, if required.
    ]
}

struct MyAppVersionedSchema: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 0, 0)

    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [
        Entry.self, Tag.self, Collection.self
    ]
}
```

So I would like to get a NSManagedObjectContext with the same persistent container as the SwiftData document. I think the place to do it is in MainWindowView(). But I am at a lost on how to make it happen. I have tried looking into view global environment objects like documentConfiguration, modelContext, and managedObjectContext but failed to make the managedObjectContext share the same container as modelContext.

Any info/hint is greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/adopting_swiftdata_for_a_core_data_app

Comment: I think you need to switch completely to Core Data if you need specific Core Data functionality

Comment: Thank you. I am slowly coming to that realization. But I was hoping that maybe somebody has done something like this with a document-based SwiftData app.